# Django Token Issue and Scopes

Tags: python, django, scope, oauth-2.0

I am developing an API which will be used by various level of users. This API is authenticated using Django OAuth2. Now what i want is to restrict the use of views based on scope. So if there is a view that performs some search then required scope should be 'search'.

For this purpose Django does provide class based views where we just fill a list of required_scopes. However the issue is i want to restrict the scope of token while issuing them.

So when a user request for a token I want to check the user who has requested the token and then add scopes accordingly. I do not know how to manipulate these scopes.

Please i really require help on this. I have been stuck on it for a long time

Thanx in advance

Comment: you may have to look "Authentication & Permissions" in djangorestframework

Comment: I have read all. It does not help

Answer (score 1):

when you use OAuth2 you have token for check user authentication you can set your token in browser with cookie and save with session id 
example :

```
if 'x-auth-token' in request.session:
    return HttpResponse("sorry you have account")
```

with this below example you can set your cookie :

```
response.set_cookie(key="token", value=token)
```

Comment: This is not a root solution. If i can just control the scopes during the issue of token that will be a very smooth workflow. But i just do not know how to do it